# Plus/Minus on Accordion -- ID's or Array?

Tags: jquery

I'm adjusting an accordion which uses h3 for each title, and lists for the content within.  I'm trying to add a plus when an item is not open, and a minus when it is.  I've had some luck editing the script, but it detects that ANY of the items are open, not just the one being clicked.

I'm not sure if I need unique ID's on each h3, or an array of some sort.  Any help appreciated.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    $("#accordian h3").css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/plus.png)');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#accordian h3").css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/minus.png)');
        $(this).next().slideDown();

    }
})
```

})

Comment: Hi, this question would be super quick to fix if you added some code to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) e.g.

Comment: Non-unique IDs would not be IDs ;-P

Comment: here is jsfiddle with some of my code...just imagine actual plus and minus signs are there  =p

http://jsfiddle.net/jY6Mf/

Answer (score 0):

with this line

```
$("#accordian h3").css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/minus.png)');
```

you're adding the minus icon to all h3 including the one your just click, change the selector with 'this'

```
$(this).css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/minus.png)');
```

where 'this' it's the H3 you clicked

**Demo** (i remove all the jquery code you added )

http://jsfiddle.net/jY6Mf/3/